# Unable to authenticate through JQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

When i send post request through jquery(Cross domain) it is not authenticated and in response null is coming while i am sending same request through using burp suite or http live header then it is working and able to authenticate please suggest me solution for the problem

Comment: Have you tried using JSONP to send your requests?

Comment: Please see [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: I Have tried Using JSONP and jquery.

Comment: I Am Sending using jQuery.post

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). You can not make requests to other domains with the XMLHttpRequest object.

Most modern day browsers support CORS or you can use JSONP if you can make a GET request. If you can not use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), you need to use a proxy on your server to send/retrieve the content.

Comment: But if other domain is not onned by me then will it possible through JSONP .Since it also require some header.proxy server thing will not work in my case because i need to set cookies in user browser .Can you give me some detail about CORS implementation

Comment: Since i can not set Access-Control-Allow-Origin this type of header

Comment: since you do not 'own' the other domain, you need to use a proxy on your sever.

Comment: but in this cas i can set cookies in client browser

Comment: If you're using Jquery Ajax set to true the option crossDomain. That's valid since version 1.5